# jFreeChart: How to hide items from legend?

Tags: jfreechart

I need to hide every second/third/forth item from the legend. IS there a way to achieve this in jFreeChart?
thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

okay, just did it myself. This way I remove every second item from the legend.
please leave comments!

```
LegendItemCollection legendItemsOld = plot.getLegendItems();
final LegendItemCollection legendItemsNew = new LegendItemCollection();

for(int i = 0; i< legendItemsOld.getItemCount(); i++){
  if(!(i%2 == 0)){
    legendItemsNew.add(legendItemsOld.get(i));
  }
}
LegendItemSource source = new LegendItemSource() {
LegendItemCollection lic = new LegendItemCollection();
{lic.addAll(legendItemsNew);}
public LegendItemCollection getLegendItems() {  
    return lic;
}
};
chart.addLegend(new LegendTitle(source));
```

Comment: That's good for a dynamic solution.  It's also possible to use renderer.getLegendItems() and plot.setFixedLegendItems().  This yields a simpler solution, but is only good if your legend won't be changing after you set the fixed legend.  I don't have time to craft the details of the solution, but look for getLegendItems and setFixedLegendItems in AbstractXYItemRenderer and XYPlot.

Answer (score 8):

I have tried the above suggestion but it didn't seem to work for me. If you just want to remove series from the legend you can do it with the `setSeriesVisibleInLegend()` method. My scenario was that some of my series do not have a legend key. If they don't have a legend key then the series shouldn't be visible in the legend. I implemented this with the following code:

```
    for(int i = 0; i < seriesList.size(); i++){

        if(seriesList.get(i).getKey() == null || seriesList.get(i).getKey().equals("")){
            graph.getXYPlot().getRenderer().setSeriesVisibleInLegend(i, Boolean.FALSE);
        }
    }
```

The `seriesList` is a list of `seriesData` pojo's that I created that holds all of the graph data to create the graph. If the `seriesData` object's key value is `null` or `= ""` then the series will not be visible in the legend.